# Redux React-Native: Undefined object after updating the state

Tags: react-native, redux

I have set up reducers, action and store and they seem to work fine. However, when I try to access the store via this.props, I get undefined object. Any idea why this might be happening?

Index.js:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
        render() {
                console.log("##########################")
                console.log(this.props)
                this.props.dispatchloggedInUser("User found");
                console.log(this.props.dispatchGetUser())
                console.log("###########################")

                return <Root/>;
            }
}
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            dispatchloggedInUser: (data) => dispatch(loggedInUser(data)),
            dispatchGetUser: () => dispatch(getUser())
        }
    }
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            user: state.user
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Index)
```

AuthReducer:

```
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGGED_IN: {
            console.log("Inside Logged IN")
            console.log(state)
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    user: action.data
                }
            ]
        }

        case GET_USER: {
            return {...state }
        }

        default:
            return { ...state }
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Basically, if youre using combine reducers, make sure you account for multilevel states.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your root reducer - the user is probably nested under `auth` or something similar - to find out:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        user: state.auth.user // or ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats definitely one of the things to look at but it was set up correctly in my case. I was able to fix it (updated the question)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this part:

```
case LOGGED_IN: {
    console.log("Inside Logged IN")
    console.log(state)
    return [
        ...state,
       {
           user: action.data
       }
    ]
}
```

to...

```
case LOGGED_IN: {
    console.log("Inside Logged IN")
    console.log(state)
    let user = action.data
    return {...state, user}
}
```